# C++ string length

Tags: c++, string, string-length

I was reading the documentation of [`string::length`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/length/) and, as you can see, it says that

> Returns the length of the string, in terms of bytes.

So my question is, is this ensured to be also the number of char that it contains?
I know that usually a `char` is `1 byte`, but is this ensured somewhere? Like in the standard or somewhere else?

Comment: The documentation states pretty clearly, *Returns the length of the string, in terms of bytes.*. If it is using multi-byte characters, it is still returning number of bytes, not number of characters.

Comment: I think [this `length` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) have it much better worded: "Returns the number of `CharT` elements in the string," (a `char` doesn't have to be a "byte").

Comment: To prevent solving an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/217657), let me ask: What is your real use case?

Comment: btw `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition (not just "usually")

Comment: cplusplus.com is not an official reference. It's written by "enthusiasts", not experts, and is often confusing (and sometimes even wrong ).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so, i can use string::length and be sure that it returns the number of chars, right?

Comment: It returns the number of *elements* that the string holds. One element might correspond to a single character, or it might be part of e.g. a multi-byte UTF-8 sequence.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think you are misunderstanding the term “char” used by OP. It seems not to mean _character_ but “bytes (objects of type _char_)” as https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size defines it.

Comment: @idclev463035818 and so why long sometimes on some architecture is 4 byte and in others 8?